# Enforce unique values based on multiple columns

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to enforce unique values based on 3 columns. i'm trying for SharePoint online.

1. Lookup column
2. Choice
3. Calendar (only date)

I tried with below code, able to retrieve the existing values from the list but Calendar date selection is getting failed. not able to figure out what can be done. can anyone help on this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/Mysite/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    
    //variable to hold Ajax result
    var dataResults;
     var call = $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Mylist')/Items?" + "$select=Title,Engagement,Period",     
//Title is a lookup column          
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async:false,
            headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function(data) {
            dataResults = data.d;
             
                     
            }    
       
        });
        
        
        function PeriodValue(fullDate){
        
        var orderDateString = "2016-10-19T22:00.00Z"; //UTC datetime value from REST response 
        var orderDate = new Date(orderDateString);
        var value= TimeZoneUtilities.utcToLocalTime(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,orderDate);
      alert(value);
        var dateValue=null,twoDigitDate=null,twoDigitMonth=null,twoDigitYear,currentDate=null;
          dateValue = fullDate.split("T")[0];
          twoDigitDate = dateValue.split("-")[2];
          twoDigitMonth = dateValue.split("-")[1];
          twoDigitYear = dateValue.split("-")[0];
          currentDate = twoDigitDate + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" + twoDigitYear;
        return currentDate;
        }   
                
    //function to compare user input and existing data
    function PreSaveAction(){
        var ClientName = document.querySelector('[title="Client Name Required Field"]');
        var engagement = document.querySelector('[title="Engagement Required Field"]');
        var period = document.querySelector('[title="Period Required Field"]');
        ClientName=ClientName.options[ClientName.selectedIndex].text;
        engagement=engagement.options[engagement.selectedIndex].text;
        period=period.value;
        var c = null;
        
                
        $.each(dataResults, function(i, item){
        
            c = true;
            $.each(item, function(i, dt){
                        
                 console.log(dt.Engagement + '  ' + dt.Period + ' ' +dt.Title);
                if (dt.Engagement == engagement  && dt.Period == period && dt.Title==ClientName){
                    c = false;
                    alert("Already exist");
                    return c;
                }
            });
        });           
        return c;  
    }
    
</script>​​
```

Comment: What is the usage of function PeriodValue()?You'd better share more information about the list.

Comment: I'm using PeriodValue(), for Calendar (only date) column to retrieve date value from the list items and compare the date column with new item value. While retrieving the date value it is in this format  "2016-10-19T22:00.00Z" with -1 date.

Comment: But it did not be called in the script.

Comment: please let me know for any corrections in the code.

Comment: You'd better share detailed list information,so that I could test with your directly,There should be no problem with the logic of the code.Or you could try to debug the code to find reason.

Comment: Can you please share your mail id or contact number to reach directly to you for sharing the details. Your help  is really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Sorry,company policy does not allow this.

Comment: no worries. Thank you for your support